# wcf with https without iis

Tags: c#, wcf, https

I currently have a Windows service that hosts a WCF service.This WCF service used to have an endpoint for net.tcp but now the service must be available outside our domain.

The information on the internet was scarce to find info on how to use https without IIS because every example I found was with IIS.

what I have so far is these configs: **server**:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <clientCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
          </clientCertificate>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="JdnNetRootCA" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Jdn.Historian.Service.HistorianService">
    <endpoint address="https://localhost/Historian" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Jdn.Historian.Schema.Service.IHistorian" />
  </service>
</services>
```

**client**

```
<bindings>
   <wsHttpBinding>
     <binding>
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
     </binding>
   </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://localhost/Historian" binding="wsHttpBinding"
             contract="Historian.IHistorian" behaviorConfiguration="secure">            
  </endpoint>
</client>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="secure">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="JdnNetRootCA" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="Root"/>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and the host is initialized like this:

```
var host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(Historian.Service.HistorianService));
host.Open();
```

but I can't get it working. I get the error:

> An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://localhost/Historian. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

I tried searching the error, but there is no concrete solution. I first want to make sure my implementation is correct. 
So, is this the correct way of doing this? or does anyone know how to fix this issue

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/james_osbornes_blog/2010/12/10/selfhosting-a-wcf-service-over-https/

Comment: this is indeed a blog that explains everything. Man, my google skills are declining. thanks for the link